# Conver Vanilla JS to React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, parallax

I'm new with react. I'm trying to convert my vanilla js parallax effect in to react but I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'top')".

Here is my vanilla js script:

```
<script>
    let text = document.getElementById('text');
    let sun = document.getElementById('sun');
    let house = document.getElementById('house');
    let bird1 = document.getElementById('bird1');
    let bird2 = document.getElementById('bird2');
    let forest = document.getElementById('forest');
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    let header = document.getElementById('header');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        let value = window.scrollY;
        text.style.top = 50 + value * -0.5 + '%';
        btn.style.marginTop = value * .7 + 'px';
        sun.style.marginTop = value * -2 + 'px';
        house.style.marginTop = value * -0.7 + 'px';
        bird1.style.top = value * -1.5 + 'px';
        bird1.style.left = value * 2 + 'px';
        bird2.style.top = value * -1.5 + 'px';
        bird2.style.left = value * -5 + 'px';
        header.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px';
    })
</script>
```

What I've tried in react is this:

```
function ParallaxHero() {

 const textRef = useRef();
 const sunRef = useRef();
 const houseRef = useRef();
 const bird1Ref = useRef();
 const bird2Ref = useRef();
 const forestRef = useRef();
 const iconRef = useRef();
 const waterRef = useRef();

 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    let value = window.scrollY;
    textRef.style.top = 50 + value * -0.5 + '%';
    iconRef.style.marginTop = value * .7 + 'px';
    sunRef.style.marginTop = value * -2 + 'px';
    houseRef.style.marginTop = value * -0.7 + 'px';
    bird1Ref.style.top = value * -1.5 + 'px';
    bird1Ref.style.left = value * 2 + 'px';
    bird2Ref.style.top = value * -1.5 + 'px';
    bird2Ref.style.left = value * -5 + 'px';
    waterRef.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px';
  })
})

return (
  <>
   <div className='parallax relative'>
    <h1 ref={textRef} className='parallax-text'>BOOKINGS, IN A HEARTBEAT.</h1>
    <Image ref={sunRef} className="parallax-image" src={sunImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
    <Image ref={houseRef} className="parallax-image" src={houseImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
    <Image ref={bird1Ref} className="parallax-image" src={birdOneImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
    <Image ref={bird2Ref} className="parallax-image" src={birdTwoImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
    <Image ref={forestRef} className="parallax-image" src={forestImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
    <a href="#" ref={iconRef} className='parallax-button'>Explore</a>
    <Image ref={waterRef} className="parallax-image" src={waterImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
   </div>
  </>
 )
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try adding current to the ref like `textRef.current.style.top` .

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I got this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to study 'useRef' more in detail https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#usage

Also, keep a note when you will change the object like textRef.current.style.top, it won't trigger the rendering cycle as it is not mutating the original object. The object is always referred to with 'current', so any value change will go to the same object.

Try below code:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  let ref = useRef({style:{}});
useEffect(()=>{
  ref.current.style.top = 2;
  console.log("Prop: ", ref.current.style.top)
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A [ref](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) is an object that always contains the current reference to the element, in the 'current' property.

Also note that the event listener that you add to window needs to be cleaned up after an unmount, you can do this by returning a cleanup function in the [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect). *(otherwise .style would be accessed on undefined and you would get a bunch of "Cannot read properties of undefined" errors)*

```
function ParallaxHero() {

  const textRef = useRef();
  const sunRef = useRef();
  const houseRef = useRef();
  const bird1Ref = useRef();
  const bird2Ref = useRef();
  const forestRef = useRef();
  const iconRef = useRef();
  const waterRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let scrollHandler = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      textRef.current.style.top = 50 + value * -0.5 + '%';
      iconRef.current.style.marginTop = value * .7 + 'px';
      sunRef.current.style.marginTop = value * -2 + 'px';
      houseRef.current.style.marginTop = value * -0.7 + 'px';
      bird1Ref.current.style.top = value * -1.5 + 'px';
      bird1Ref.current.style.left = value * 2 + 'px';
      bird2Ref.current.style.top = value * -1.5 + 'px';
      bird2Ref.current.style.left = value * -5 + 'px';
      waterRef.current.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    return ()=>{
      window.removeEventListener("scroll",scrollHandler);
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
    <div className='parallax relative'>
      <h1 ref={textRef} className='parallax-text'>BOOKINGS, IN A HEARTBEAT.</h1>
      <Image ref={sunRef} className="parallax-image" src={sunImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
      <Image ref={houseRef} className="parallax-image" src={houseImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
      <Image ref={bird1Ref} className="parallax-image" src={birdOneImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
      <Image ref={bird2Ref} className="parallax-image" src={birdTwoImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
      <Image ref={forestRef} className="parallax-image" src={forestImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
      <a href="#" ref={iconRef} className='parallax-button'>Explore</a>
      <Image ref={waterRef} className="parallax-image" src={waterImage} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" alt="Sun Image" />
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```